# Stop view blinking thread

Tags: android

I have function that starts thread for blinking view if accepted true, but how do I stop it if false received?

```
private void blinkText(boolean b){

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    if(b)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            int timeToBlink = 1000;    //in ms
            try{
                Thread.sleep(timeToBlink);
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    if(txt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    blinkText(true);
                }
                });
            }}).start();
    }

    else
    {
        // stop blinking
    }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use Android Animations for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a blinking animation in xml and add it to your textview after initialising it:

**res/anim/blink.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:duration="200"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</alpha>
```

**Add animation to view:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);

        TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        Animation blink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.blink);
        textView.setAnimation(blink);
    }
```

**To start:**

`textView.getAnimation().start()`

**To stop:**

```
textView.getAnimation().cancel()
textView.getAnimation().reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a boolean field as class member ( boolean mStopBlink = false; ) and track of whether the TextView is currently blink:

```
txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if(!mStopBlink){
    txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```